# Regex to extract a specific string in URL

Tags: java, regex

I want to extract one string from URL  and seeking your help to find the regex for the same .

String is   [http://somewebsite.come/v1/dataRes/54d7898-dfa9-4f5b-a23e-34575g678d5]
 I want to extract last part opf the URL which is:54d7898-dfa9-4f5b-a23e-34575g678d5

Right now I am doing a lot of hard coded which does not look good . Can anyone suggest a better approach ?

```
    List<String> test = headersStr.get("keyLoc");
        System.out.println(test.toString()); // Prints [http://somewebsite.come/v1/dataRes/54d7898-dfa9-4f5b-a23e-34575g678d5] 
        String[] strArr = test.toString().substring(7,test.toString().length() - 1).split("/");
        String profileId = strArr[4];
        System.out.println("Profile Id :"+profileId);
```

Comment: `String str = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf(“/“)+1);`

Comment: Thank you very much ..        String temp = line.substring(line.lastIndexOf("/")+1,line.length()-1); Works perfect ..